# Securing IIS 10 WebDav enabled virtual folder with ADFS

Tags: iis, adfs, webdav

We have an ASP.NET MVC Application hosted in IIS, configured with ADFS authentication.
The ADFS configuration is provided via OWIN middleware.

Inside the application (in its root) there is a WebDav enabled virtual folder on which are stored the documents.

When trying to access the application the user is asked for credentials via ADFS and logon process is configured properly.

The documents (from the webdav folder) are listed in the home page and we want after click on document link, to open the document via microsoft office and to interact.

We access document with the following url:

ms-word:ofe|u|https://app.webdav/Documents/document.docx

and trying to do inline editing after which the changes should be stored directly in the server.

The problem is that popup dialog for authentication in office doesn't display and changes can not be saved directly in the server (Access denied).
We don't have this problem if we enable windows authentication.

My questions are:

- How to setup WEBDAV on IIS for ADFS authentication?
- Will Microsoft Office handle the interaction with ADFS?

Comment: Kindly check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767258/securing-an-iis-7-webdav-enabled-virtual-folder-with-adfs) where it is already answered .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found also that link but it doesn't solve the problem for me. In the answer it is stated the following: "So, we ended up doing the required authentication without ADFS.". I'm trying currently configuration with Workfolders with ADFS authentication. I will write if I found any answer